# What do "implicit sequence" and "implicit index" mean in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I just created a table in Postgres and received a notice message that I do not completely understand regarding implicit indexes and sequences. Any clarification would be appreciated.

```
my_database=# CREATE TABLE sites
my_database-# (
my_database(# site_id_key serial primary key,
my_database(# site_url VARCHAR(255),
my_database(# note VARCHAR(255),
my_database(# type INTEGER,
my_database(# last_visited TIMESTAMP
my_database(# ) ;
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE will create implicit sequence "sites_site_id_key_seq" for serial column "sites_to_search.site_id_key"
NOTICE:  CREATE TABLE / PRIMARY KEY will create implicit index "sites_pkey" for table "sites_to_search"
CREATE TABLE
```

Comment: These are just notifications that postgresql automagically created a sequence and index for you.

Comment: @TI Thanks for your reply! So I am guessing that I will have two indexes for this table, the primary key I created and implicit index. And that the sequence is the step between each number in the index?

Comment: No, you'll only have 1 index unless you create more manually. PostgreSQL is just warning you that since the primary key needs an index, it's creating one. Same thing with the sequence, except it's not the primary key that needs one, it's the `SERIAL` data type. "Implicit" just refers to the fact that PostgreSQL is creating things you didn't ask for explicitly. You didn't ask for an index or a sequence, but those are *implied* by other things you did ask for.

Comment: The SERIAL and BIGSERIAL datatypes are just syntactic sugar for the db creating the sequence for you, setting it as the default for the column, and granting ownership to the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certain things in PostgreSQL are handled by indexes and sequences.  These include serial and bigserial types, unique constraints, and primary keys.  These are not implicit in PostgreSQL (so the notice is a little misleading) but rather implicit in the DDL that PostgreSQL is running.

In other words, the indexes and sequences are just normal indexes and sequences.  They are just automatically created by PostgreSQL in order to provide the guarantees and features you have requested in your DDL.